# $p$-groups and the arithmetic of $p$

Tags: gr.group-theory, big-list

I cannot think of an example of a property of a $p$-group or a pro-$p$ group that depends on the arithmetic of the prime number $p$. To clarify l do not mean the size of $p$. Clearly lots of stuff happen only for some small $p$ or large enough $p$. I am interested in properties that happen for infinitely many primes $p$ and do not happen also for infinitely many other $p$. So for instance, a property that depends whether $p$ is congruent to 1 modulo 4.

Can you give such examples?

Comment: The classification of 6-dimensional nilpotent Lie algebras over an arbitrary field involves some families $g(t)$ with one parameter $t$ such that $g(t)$ and $g(u)$ are isomorphic iff $t/u$ is a square. So from this one can build $p$-groups (of exponent $p$) $G(t)$ with the same property. Thus one gets $G(t)$ isomorphic to $G(-1)$ iff $p$ equals 1 modulo 4 (with some explicit description of $G(t)$).

Comment: Explicit example (based on $L_{6,22}$ in de Graaf's classification): consider $e\in\{\pm 1\}$ and $G_{p,e}$ the $p$-group ($p$ odd) with presentation with generators $s_1\dots,s_6$ all of exponent $p$, $s_5,s_6$ central, and $[s_1,s_2]=s_5$, $[s_1,s_3]=s_6$, $[s_3,s_4]=s_5$, $[s_2,s_4]=s_6^e$. Then $G_{p,-1}$ is isomorphic to $G_{p,1}$ iff $p$ is 1 mod 4. (I haven't checked but possibly this is equivalent to $G_{p,-1}$ being a direct product of two groups of order $p^3$).

Comment: Doesn't the number of groups of order $p^r$ depend on whether the prime $p$ is even or odd?

Comment: @GerryMyerson that would not be something holding for infinitely many $p$ and not holding for infinitely many $p$, which is the OP's criterion.

Comment: The automorphism group of $\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z$ is $(\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z)^\times$, so properties of $(\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z)^\times$ could be regarded as properties of (automorphisms of) the $p$-group $\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z$. For example, since $(\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z)^\times$ is cyclic, $\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z$ has an automorphism of order $n$ if and only if $p \equiv 1 \bmod n$.

Comment: But following on from Gerry Myerson's comment, the classification of $p$-groups of orders $p^5$, $p^6$, and $p^7$ depends on the congruence of $p$ modulo various small numbers, so it could be said in  these cases that various types of groups arise and do not arise for infinitely many primes $p$.

Comment: @DerekHolt your answered reminded me about the PORC conjecture and actually that Marcus Du Sautoy proved a version of it. Would you like to put it as answer? If not, I can do it.

Comment: @KConrad, I was sure that would be something about abelian groups, as it essentially number theory. Why don't you put it as answer?

Comment: I was under the impression that Marcus Du Sautoy's work (with Michael Vaughan-Lee) was regarded as evidence that the PORC conjecture might be false, but I believe that more recent work on the topic is less clear in this respect. Rather than answer, I will just point for the moment to the [wikipedia page](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Higman%27s_PORC_conjecture)